# How does one come up with a new logic system?

Tags: logic

During a seminar at Indiana University, the professor mentioned that one can define his own logic system. I wonder if there is any references on coming up with a new logical system and prove that the new system is sound and complete?

Comment: See e.g. [Non-classical logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-classical_logic)

Comment: If you are interested in "coming up" with your own "new" logical system, the notions of [soundness and completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundness) will be defined in terms of your definition of *validity* of a formula.  I recommend you do some research before posting further on the topic of "a new logic system" because as currently framed the Question is overly broad.

Comment: I would note that you can define a logic purely syntactically (i.e. proof theoretically). No notion of semantics needs to be provided which would mean there's nothing for soundness and completeness to refer to. Soundness and completeness are relationships between a logic and its semantics. If you define a "new" logic, you will likely also need to define a "new" notion of semantics as well. You can look at the [theory of institutions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Institution_(computer_science)) for a framework in which to do this.